# Fequency at which location history gets my location?

Tags: google, google-maps, geolocation, google-location-history

I've noticed that Google Location History tracks my position much more frequently and accurately when having Google Maps actively running, compared to when it is not. Is this the case for any app – whenever the GPS is on – or just when Google apps tracks my position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "start driving" feature in Google Maps saves your position every 15 seconds. (That's what I do)
Using any other app to require exact gps position in background is less accurate (same accuracy but less frequent data points).